# Getting an error Socket is trying to reconnect to Sails

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, sails.js

My Sails version is 0.11.2 and running with port 1337

In assets/js/dependencies/sails.io.js, i can see version as 0.11.0

Below is the client side script.

```
<script src="http://localhost/project/assets/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// `io` is available as a global.
// `io.socket` will connect automatically, but at this point in the DOM, it is not ready yet
// (think of $(document).ready() from jQuery)
//
// Fortunately, this library provides an abstraction to avoid this issue.
// Requests you make before `io` is ready will be queued and replayed automatically when the socket connects.
// To disable this behavior or configure other things, you can set properties on `io.sails`.
// You have one cycle of the event loop to set `io.sails.autoConnect` to false before the auto-connection
// behavior starts.

io.socket.get('/hello', function serverResponded (body, JWR) {

  // JWR ==> "JSON WebSocket Response"
  console.log('Sails responded with: ', body);
  console.log('with headers: ', JWR.headers);
  console.log('and with status code: ', JWR.statusCode);

  // first argument `body` === `JWR.body`
  // (just for convenience, and to maintain familiar usage, a la `JQuery.get()`)
});
```

I am getting the error like

```
Socket is trying to reconnect to Sails...
```

When i checked some other posts, there saying something related with sails version. 
I tried to change the sails.io.js version to 0.11.2, but still same error.

Is this error have any connection with port ?
Because the response from below request is 404

```
http://localhost/socket.io/?__sails_io_sdk_version=0.11.2&__sails_io_sdk_platform=browser&__sails_io_sdk_language=javascript&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1444654910110-52
```

Response

```
<p>The requested URL /socket.io/ was not found on this server.</p>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
```

Any help what is wrong ?

Answer (score 5):

You're running the Sails app on port 1337, but loading the `sails.io.js` file from port 80 (because you don't specify another port):

```
<script src="http://localhost/project/assets/js/dependencies/sails.io.js">
```

I guess you have an Apache server running on port 80, so it's finding the `sails.io.js` file and returning it, but then the socket client assumes that it should be connecting on port 80 as well.

Either update your `script` tag with a port:

```
<script src="http://localhost:1337/js/dependencies/sails.io.js">
```

or specify an alternate URL for the socket to connect to, using the following code before the `io.socket.get`:

```
io.sails.url = "http://localhost:1337";
```

Comment: Cool...realized that I didn't give you the correct path for the `.js` file when loading it from Sails (since it exposes the `assets` folder as the _root_ of your public files).   Fixed now so both options should work.

Comment: Yes right about exposing the actual project path.
I changed the way according to your suggestion.

 <script src="http://localhost:1337/js/dependencies/sails.io.js">
io.sails.url = "http://localhost:1337";
Seems to be required both lines.
   Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: @sgress454 I know I should create a new question for this, but didn't find any solutions. I have nginx as a proxy server so when /node/anything is requested it is redirected to localhost:3000, The front-end application has a reference for socket.io.js which resides in sails API application using `script type="text/javascript" src="/node/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>` 
<script type="text/javascript">
      io.sails.url = '/node';
    </script> cause the same error. Any help

Answer (score 0):

The 404 is coming from a client-side socket attempting to connect to the server, which is not accepting socket connections.

if you are not using a socket in your application you need to **delete the sails.io.js script**.

and below both options didn't work for me but this worked. I deleted the sails.io.js file.